# Why are requests for tutorials closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I saw a question recently where the questioner had almost no experience designing databases, and wanted to learn how to do the design right before plunging in to a project.  The questioner asked for references that could teach him/her this material.

It was closed as "not a real question".  This surprises me.  Is it common to close such questions?  Should it be common?

---

OK, here's the link  to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953268/step-by-step-database-design-reference).

Comment: Link to question?

Answer (score 2):

Thousands of tutorials to choose from.  The OP didn't nearly spend enough time to explain exactly *what* he needs help with.  As-is, the answer would be "all of them" which makes it a worthless question.  Properly closed.

Comment: I would have at least referred the OP to CJ DATE:  An Introduction to Database Systems.  That could well be overkill in his case, but it's the gold standard of database texts.

Comment: The fact that you *don't know* whether or not it is overkill is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not common to close such questions which ask for tutorials. There are lot of such questions which ask for tutorials which have been answered too. Probably in the case you have mentioned, the question could've been closed because of existing duplicate.

You can post that example question which will make it clear on why it was marked for closure.

Comment: Agreed. This was probably a case of "too lazy to search for a dupe, thus closing as not a real question"

Comment: Then who is more correct in their display of laziness? Why wouldn't it be closed as a duplicate, was the closer too lazy to...? 'Two wrongs...' Just a thought.