# Are we allowed to post how-to examples on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I've seen that there aren't a lot of examples showing how to get mp3 tags and properties.
So I was just wondering, is it possible to post a how-to example to help people who might be looking for that information, or is Stack Overflow the wrong site for that kind of thing?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92306/should-so-become-the-place-to-come-to-find-good-getting-started-tutorials

Answer (score 6):

You can, but you need to post it in the form of a question and answer.

So the question would be "How do I get mp3 tags and properties?" with enough details of course.

Then you post an answer which shows how it's done.

However, I'm sure that there are already some questions on this on SO. In fact I've already [answered one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361587/where-can-i-find-tag-lib-sharp-examples/4361634#4361634)