# Should users asking for beginner tutorials instead post a request on Meta Stack Overflow for an update to the relevant tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, site-crossover

This is a follow-up to *[Should Stack Overflow become the place to come to find good “getting started” tutorials?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92306/143302)* and **CrazyJugglerDrummer's comment "Prominent tutorial links could also be added to tag-wikis."**

Is it appropriate to direct users asking "How do I get started with xyz?" to post an question on Meta Stack Overflow asking for an according update to the related tag info wiki (like other "could someone please update tag wiki xyz" requests) if there is no useful information in it yet?

---

*Edit*

I'm tempted to rollback the title edit since it changes the meaning to something very different.

- I don't steer towards resurrecting the [getting-started](/questions/tagged/getting-started) tag; it was a meta-tag and is well burniated.
- I consider questions on "Where can I find tutorials on getting started with xyz?" as NARQ and vote to close without hesitation.
- I don't want to have tutorials on the tag wiki pages - just links to good resources.

I just think it would be more constructive to point users to a tag wiki instead of linking to *[Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/143302)*.

If some tag wiki doesn't have any useful information about "Getting started", why not allow to ask for an update/edit here on Meta Stack Overflow? Maintaining tag wiki pages that way IMO would be time well spent and add valuable content to Stack Overflow - better than burying those links in answers to those questions (and dozens of their duplicates).

Answer (score 7):

**IMO I wouldn't want to see requests on meta for tag wiki updates** -

> could someone please update tag wiki [someothertag](/questions/tagged/someothertag)

As it stands today, **all** questions of that nature will be closed and promptly deleted.  It is not constructive.  It is asking someone to do far more than answer a question or make a comment.

If someone is asking "`How do I get started with xyz?`", the correct response would be open your favourite IDE and browser - navigate to the documentation/tutorial of your choice and start learning!  That might be a little bit brutal but such an open ended question has no place on SO... [We are not personal research assistants](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172936).

Just as you don't ask people to answer your questions you wouldn't ask people to update the tag wiki for you.   A question is asked and if some user comes across it and feels that they are able to answer it or help out the OP somehow then so be it.  Similarly, if a user comes across a tag wiki that lacks information (and feels the desire to help out) it is their and **only** their decision whether or not to make an edit...

There was a reason that the [getting-started](/questions/tagged/getting-started) tag was part of  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012.  Those questions are not specific enough.

Comment: Nice Answer :)..

Comment: My reasoning was that SO would accumulate valuable starting points and it would be a target you could guide users to when they post questions "Where can I find something about getting started ...". Plus with some SEO + luck, in search results "Getting started with xyz" from tag wiki pages will be among the top 10. And it would simply be more constructive than: NARQ + FGIY.

Comment: But that is simply not what the site is about.  **Yes we are about helping people** - but we do it in the Q&A format and not as long tutorials that might be better of being on someones blog.  People could read it there, learn from it, there, and if they have a **specific question** about how to implement a part of it, **then** would be a good time to come on down and post an awesome interesting question.

Comment: I don't question the Q&A format of SO; I just want to improve tag wiki pages by having links to external tutorials and to that end I suggest posting on MSO if for a given tag wiki no such links exist. Nothing more and nothing less. Please check my edited post on what I **not** intend. Also consider that the title edit suggested that I promote polluting MSO with NARQ otherwise asked on SO - this is not what I intend.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are correct.

Rather than asking directly that question on SO. First user must to search/google it, if user doesn't get correct results or proper explanation then he/she may post that question to Stack Overflow. So the experts or the person gone trough same problem may help him.

sometimes the links of tutorials are not directly serve in front of us and this problem mostly happens with new comers, who do not make use of proper keywords while searching any tutorial or topic.

Comment: Not being able to find a *good* tutorial is **not** a reason to ask for one on [so]... That question will be closed because of the lack of specificity...

Comment: @Lix I don't advocate asking those questions on SO. I vote to close a good deal of them myself every day. I simply seek a more constructive way of dealing with this. There are tag wikis already providing good staring points and I think SO should strive to achieve this for as many tag wiki pages as possible.